# Querydsl update clause populate skips bean null value properties

Tags: java, querydsl

I have problem with SQLUpdateClause when using populate call with bean's null value properties. It just skips null value properties from generated update SQL instead of setting corresponding fields to NULL.

Example:

```
public class Bean {

    private Long id;

    private String value;

    private String value2;

    ...
}

Bean bean = ...

bean.setValue(null);
bean.setValue("value2");

SQLUpdateClause update = new SQLUpdateClause(connection, dialect, qBean);

update.populate(bean).where(qBean.id.eq(...)).execute();
```

Will produce SQL:

```
update bean set value2 = 'value2' where bean.id = ...
```

Instead of desired:

```
update bean set value = null, value2 = 'value2' where bean.id = ...
```

Any help here? ... please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When checked querydsl source code, found out solution:

```
...
update.populate(bean, DefaultMapper.WITH_NULL_BINDINGS)
      .where(qBean.id.eq(...))
      .execute();
...
```

Hope it helps someone